# ¿Como registrar usuarios en ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Mi codigo es este para registrar usuarios:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult RegistrarUsuario([Bind(Include = "estado")] Usuarios usuarios)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        Conectar();
        string password = GetStringSha256Hash(usuarios.contrasena);

        string query = "Insert into usuarios (nombre, apellido, correo, contrasena)"+
            "VALUES (@nombre, @apellido, @correo, @contrasena)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", usuarios.nombre);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellido", usuarios.apellido);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correo", usuarios.correo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contrasena", password);


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");


    }
```

y al momento de registrar me manda el siguiente error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@nombre 
nvarchar(4000),@apellido nvarchar(4000),@correo nvarcha' expects the parameter 
'@nombre', which was not supplied.'
```

Este es el modelo de mi usuario:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace LigaITIC.Models
{
public class Usuarios
{
    public int id { get; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string apellido { get; set; }
    public string correo { get; set; }
    public string contrasena { get; set; }
    public string estado { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Cuando haces debug que datos llegan en Usuario? Nombre tiene valor?. Puede ser que tu tabla en BD tenga definido que el Nombre no puede ser null pero en el post nombre esta llegando null.

Comment: Es normal que en el `[Bind]` solo incluyas `estado` y no todos los datos del modelo que quieres agregar?

Comment: Además de lo señalado en comentarios y respuestas, en tu variable `query` debes agregar un espacio entre `contrasena)` y `VALUES (`.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el controlador que genera la vista? En otras palabras, agregar el HttpGet de RegistrarUsuario por favor :D

Answer (score 3):

En adición a lo que comenta la respuesta de [Raul Cacacho](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/155054/4499), estás recibiendo `null` en el `POST` porque estas haciendo `[Bind(Include = "estado")]`, al hacer `[Bind]`, estas enlazando los datos a una entidad, por lo que si no incluyes todos los campos de tu formulario, siempre vas a recibir `null` en esos campos.

La solución es agregar todos los campos al atributo `[Bind]`:

```
[Bind(Include = "nombre,apellido,correo,contrasena,estado")]
```

O hacer:

```
[Bind(Exclude = "")]
```

Para no excluir ningún campo, tu método quedaría más o menos así:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult RegistrarUsuario([Bind(Exclude = "")]Usuarios usuarios) {
  // ...
  return ...;
}
```

Si lo que quieres es excluir `estado` en tu `[Bind]`, entonces puedes ponerlo en la lista a excluir, que creo que es lo que inicialmente querías hacer *(Pero solo es suposición)*:

```
[Bind(Exclude = "estado")]
```

Saludos :)

Answer (score 1):

Este error da porque algunos parametros son nulos, los parámetros que son nulos no se agregan, Necesita ser `DBNull.Value`, puedes hacer esto agregando `DBNull.Value` para cada parámetro. Por ejemplo para el nombre:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", usuarios.nombre ?? DBNull.Value);
```

De  esta manera sabe que es nulo el valor y no mostara mas el error.